Workaround for a view with joined data on encrypted column
I've got a view that currently has this within:
SELECT *
FROM customers_1
LEFT JOIN customers_2
    on customers_1.last_four_of_ssn = customers_2.last_four_of_ssn 
        AND customers_1.date_of_birth = customers_2.date_of_birth 

However, our execs recently decided that DOB data needed to be encrypted. So, now my selects outside of views are
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY encKey 
            DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE encKey;
    
SELECT
    cast( CONVERT( varchar, DecryptByKey( [encrypted_dob] ) ) as date )  as unencrypted_date_of_birth 
    from...
    
        CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY encKey;

... and social security numbers follow the same encryption. This isn't a problem in most places. However, this particular view matches two customer records based on whether or not they're the same individual. When we encrypted SSNs several years ago, we changed it over to a last 4 and DOB match. Now, I have no practical way to do this view.
My initial though was to set up a table with each possible encrypted ssn having a matching key and store the key in the customers table. Before I do that: is there a better way?

Isn't the SSN already unique, so the date of birth comparison becomes redundant? Also, encrypting the same value with the same key should produce the same output, so an equality comparison should just work on encrypted values, no?

No, the encrypted values don't match. Even if they underlying soc #s are the same, table1.encrypted_ssn doesn't have the same value as table2.encrypted_ssn. The last 4 of the ssn was stored unencrypted to match with DOB because we can't join on the encrypted column in a view.
